# Multiple toggle buttons on worksheet to trigger a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have 20 toggle buttons set-up like

---

```
Public Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Check_All
    If ToggleButton1.value = True Then
        ToggleButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
    Else:
        ToggleButton1.BackColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    Check_All
    If ToggleButton2.value = True Then
        ToggleButton2.BackColor = vbGreen
        Else:
        ToggleButton2.BackColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

---

I'm attempting to get them triggered by application.onkey like:

```
Application.OnKey "%a", "Sheet1.ToggleButton1_Click"
Application.OnKey "%b", "Sheet1.ToggleButton2_Click"
```

And using the Check_all for when all the buttons are "True" it'll do the following that is supposed to revert the toggle buttons back to the "False" state before it triggers another "macro".

---

```
Sub Check_All()
    Dim tb As Object

    For Each tb In Me.OLEObjects
        If tb.ProgId = "Forms.ToggleButton.1" Then
            If tb.Object.value <> True Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    CommandButton0_Click
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton0_Click()
    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 1 To 20
        Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ToggleButton" & x).Object.value = False
    Next x
    CommandButton3_Click
End Sub
```

---

But I can't seem to get the application.onkey to work and I'm completely lost now.

This is a system that is hooked up to programmable USB buttons and I'm really relying on the onkey to function, unless there's a better way???

Comment: Is it ok if you use `CTRL + b` or `CTRL + SHIFT + b` as shortcut keys?

Comment: Yeah, I just can't get any combo to work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign macros to shortcut keys in excel. You need to simulate the toggle-button click like this:

```
Sub CtrlShiftA()
ToggleButton1.Value = Not ToggleButton1.Value
End Sub
```

Then have your toggle-button sub as you like:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    ToggleButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
Else
    ToggleButton1.BackColor = vbRed
End If
End Sub
```

Then under View -> Macros -> View Macros click Options..:

[image]

Press `Shift + A` to have `Ctrl + Shift + A` as shortcut key:

[image]

Now click OK, and enjoy your shurtcut key.

Comment: THAT'S IT!!!!! man I was going about this the hard way and I kept running into problems and conflicting values, and that just made me go deeper, wow!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @Jeremy You are very welcome. Please accept the answer if it addressed your question.

Comment: Good solution. Can simplify `Sub CtrlShiftA() : ToggleButton1.Value = Not ToggleButton1.Value : End Sub`